# Python produce error when installing whl package

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I had a package from software with .whl extension. I had follow the installation using their provided documentation. However I am facing some problem, which the console said ".whl is not supported wheel on this platform". Here is the screenshot.
[Error installing .whl package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89vLf.png)

Anyone have the solution for this problem? I am using Python version 3.12.0 with pip 24.0.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "not supported wheel on this platform" typically indicates that the wheel package you're trying to install is not compatible with your current Python version or platform.

Here are some potential solutions to resolve this issue:

- Check Python Version Compatibility:
  Ensure that the wheel package you're trying to install is compatible with Python 3.12.0. Some packages may not yet support the latest Python versions. Check the package documentation or repository for compatibility information.
- Upgrade pip:
  Your pip version (24.0) might be outdated. Try upgrading pip to the latest version using the following command:

> ```
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
> ```

- Verify Platform Compatibility:
  Make sure that the wheel package is compatible with your operating system and architecture. If you're using a 64-bit version of Python, ensure that you're installing a 64-bit wheel package.
- Install From Source:
  If a pre-built wheel package is not available or compatible, consider installing the package from its source distribution (.tar.gz or .zip file) using pip. You can download the package source from the package repository and install it using pip:

> pip install /path/to/package/source.tar.gz

- Compile From Source:
  If no pre-built wheel or source distribution is available, you may need to compile the package from its source code. This typically involves downloading the package source, navigating to its directory, and running the appropriate build commands specified in the package documentation.
- Contact Package Maintainers:
  If none of the above solutions work, consider reaching out to the maintainers of the package for assistance. They may be able to provide guidance or updates to resolve compatibility issues.